# Rails Radio button link to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I set a selected radio button in my view to perform an action in my controller. 
For example, I have 3 search actions defined in my controller, and I would like the user to select a radio button which would route the search query to the appropriate controller action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass two params to your controller, the `search` and the `option` for example:

```
<%= form_tag controller_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= label_tag :option1 %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :option, "1" %>
    <%= label_tag :option2 %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :option, "2" %>
    <%= label_tag :option3 %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :option, "3" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

So, it will send through the URL the `search=` and the `option=` with some values, for example `search=some+test` and `option=1`.

Then, in your controller, you can work with these two params.... for example:

```
if params[:option] == "1"
  #do something using the params[:search]
elsif params[:option] == "2"
  #do something using the params[:search]
elsif params[:option] == "3"
  #do something using the params[:search]
else
  #do something else
...
```

I hope it helps...